# iOS Minimum OS Requirements different between Xcode project and iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I submitted an app to iTunes 7 days ago. Its status is "Waiting For Review"

I set `iOS Deployment Target` as `6.0` in the project's settings:

[image: Photo 1]

I did not do anything about minimum os version or deployment sdk in `info.plist` file:

[image: Photo 2]

I archived and submitted my app to iTunes Connect. Today, when I check `Binary Details` of my app, I see this, `"Minimum OS Requirements : 5.0"`:

[image: Photo 3]

1. Why is there a difference between my iOS Deployment Target and Minimum OS Requirements? Did I do something wrong? (e.g. `info.plist` edit?)
2. If I did something wrong, what should I do? Should I reject my binary, submit a new one and reset the review queue? Or should I contact Apple?

Comment: Select the target and see what the target's "Deployment Target" is set to. It can be different than the project. The target's value overrides whatever you have chosen for the project.

Comment: Thanks so much rmaddy. That's the problem. You should write it as answer to let me choose your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have set the "Deployment Target" to iOS 5.0 for your target. The target level settings will override any project level setting. Either remove the target level setting or update the target level setting to the proper value.

Answer (score 1):

What you did, regarding the 6.0, is only say that's the deployment to be set as, not the MINIMUM deployment. I'd say go back, check your info.plist, and check to see that the minimum os version is set to 6.0. Your min os version in your info.plist is probably set to 5.0